# Pandas - Prints from Skewness and Kurtois into one df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, printing

I used a code as follows:

```
df.skew(axis = 0, skipna = True)
df.kurt(axis = 0, skipna = True)
```

It prints the values.
How could i get these print-outs into one df (also with the feature names)?

The first column should be a feature name, the second column Skewness and the third Kurtois.

I have tried something like this, but without any success:

```
dfSKEW = df.skew(axis = 0, skipna = True)
#dfSKEW['Variable'] = dfSKEW.index
dfSKEW = dfSKEW.reset_index(drop=True)
dfSKEW.columns =['Variable', 'Skewness'] 
dfSKEW
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i found the solution:

```
dfSKEW = df.skew(axis = 0, skipna = True)
dfSKEW = dfSKEW.reset_index(drop=False)
dfSKEW.columns =['Variable', 'Skewness'] 
dfSKEW
```